# error: implicit declaration of function ‘i2c_new_device’; did you mean ‘i2c_acpi_new_device’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a C file in Ubuntu 20.04 OS.I am facing an error while running make command,I am attaching the output of the console [Error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuVZU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the new function is called:

```
i2c_new_client_device
```

Located in Linux kernel file `/include/linux/i2c.h`:

```
struct * i2c_client i2c_new_client_device(struct i2c_adapter * adap, struct i2c_board_info const * info)
```